# how to pass dynamic hostvars to ansible custom module args

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible Version : 2.13.7
Python : 3.8

Inventory file : hosts

```
all:
   hosts:
       server1:
           hostname: "abc"
           username: "abc123"
           password: "abc123"

       server2:
           hostname: "xyz"
           username: "xyz123"
           password: "xyz123"
```

Playbook : p1.yml

```
- name : Run the module
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  
  - name: Consume the values
    consume_values:
       hostname: '{{ hostvars.server1.hostname }}'
       username: '{{ hostvars.server1.username }}'
       password: '{{ hostvars.server1.password }}'
    
    consume_values:
       hostname: '{{ hostvars.server2.hostname }}'
       username: '{{ hostvars.server2.username }}'
       password: '{{ hostvars.server2.password }}'
```

Above example work perfectly.

Expectation :

But I want to have playbooks to accept all the hostvars with single entry.

1. No with_items / loops
2. should be dynamic in nature

```
- name : Run the module
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  
  - name: Consume the values
    consume_values:
       hostname: '{{ hostvars.server[0-200].hostname }}'
       username: '{{ hostvars.server[0-200].username }}'
       password: '{{ hostvars.server[0-200].password }}'
```

Another option :

below X value change to 0,1,2,3...etc.

```
- name : Run the module
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  
  - name: Consume the values
    consume_values:
       hostname: '{{ hostvars.server[X].hostname }}'
       username: '{{ hostvars.server[X].username }}'
       password: '{{ hostvars.server[X].password }}'
```

Tried below example but did not work.

```
- name : Run the module
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  
  - name: Consume the values
    consume_values:
       hostname: '{{ hostvars.server[0-200].hostname }}'
       username: '{{ hostvars.server[0-200].username }}'
       password: '{{ hostvars.server[0-200].password }}'
```

ansible-inventory :

```
{
   "_meta" : {
      "hostvars": {
           "server1": {
                "hostname":"abc"
                "username":"abc123"
                "password":"qbc123"
       }, 
           "server2": {
                "hostname":"xyz"
                "username":"xyz123"
                "password":"xyz123"
       },
   }
   
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the [*data structure*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics) of `'{{ hostvars.server[0-200].hostname }}'`. A list, perhaps?

Comment: I have added the ansible-inventory list.

Answer (score 1):

The filter [*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) serves this purpose. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
   hosts:
     server1:
       hostname: a
       username: user_a
       password: pswd_a
     server2:
       hostname: x
       username: user_x
       password: pswd_x
     server3:
       hostname: y
       username: user_y
       password: pswd_y
```

Declare the start and stop of the range, and create the list of the servers in the range

```yaml
  start: 1
  stop: 3
  servers: "{{ ['server']|product(range(start, stop + 1))|map('join') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  servers: [server1, server2, server3]
```

Then, create the lists of the attributes

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: |
       hostname: {{ servers|map('extract', hostvars, 'hostname') }}
       username: {{ servers|map('extract', hostvars, 'username') }}
       password: {{ servers|map('extract', hostvars, 'password') }}
```

---

This should be the equivalent of what you want

```yaml
       hostname: '{{ hostvars.server[1-3].hostname }}'
       username: '{{ hostvars.server[1-3].username }}'
       password: '{{ hostvars.server[1-3].password }}'
```

---

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    hostname: ['a', 'x', 'y']
    username: ['user_a', 'user_x', 'user_y']
    password: ['pswd_a', 'pswd_x', 'pswd_y']
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    start: 1
    stop: 3
    servers: "{{ ['server']|product(range(start, stop + 1))|map('join') }}"
  
  tasks:

  - debug:
      var: servers

  - debug:
      msg: |
       hostname: {{ hostvars.server1.hostname }}
       username: {{ hostvars.server1.username }}
       password: {{ hostvars.server1.password }}

  - debug:
      msg: |
       hostname: {{ servers|map('extract', hostvars, 'hostname') }}
       username: {{ servers|map('extract', hostvars, 'username') }}
       password: {{ servers|map('extract', hostvars, 'password') }}
```

---

You can put the declarations into the *group_vars*. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/aggregate.yml 
servers: "{{ ['server']|product(range(start, stop + 1))|map('join') }}"
aggregate:
  hostname: "{{ servers|map('extract', hostvars, 'hostname') }}"
  username: "{{ servers|map('extract', hostvars, 'username') }}"
  password: "{{ servers|map('extract', hostvars, 'password') }}"
```

Then, you can use the dictionary *aggregate*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: |
       hostname: {{ aggregate.hostname }}
       username: {{ aggregate.username }}
       password: {{ aggregate.password }}
    vars:
      start: 1
      stop: 3
```